# angular-material, how to add a new service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

how to add a new service to module ?

in angularjs, can be achieved like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function(){
    app.service('userService', function(){
        // .....
    });
    var service = angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp']).get('userService');
    // ......
});
```

but in angular-material, this will thow an exception.

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- $mdUtil <- $mdTheming <- $$animateQueue

**Codepen**:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/cyf/pen/YQMjda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. You can inject your service into controller and use all the methods and properties of your service.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('userService', function(){
        // .....
    });
app.controller('myController', function(userService){

    // ......
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owOaeN

For more Info: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: thanks your answer. must define service in controller. it is dynamic.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: i need async load service js-file, then inject to module

Comment: The above method will work even if you are loading js asynchronously but make sure you have injected the service to the controller for the view where you want to load the service js file async

Comment: You want to load the service file dynamically from controller on click of a button?

Comment: Idk if it is possible but if possible it will be complicated because you are trying to add a new js file to the application which is running. Why can't u just load the js file initialy?

Comment: if not use material, it can work, but in angular-material, throw same exception......

Comment: What exception are you getting? Have u included the files for angular-material and injected it into ur module?

Comment: You have not added any js files for ozlazyload and angular material

Comment: included ozlazyload.js and angular-material.js in html header

Comment: if not included, it will throw exception on "angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial", "oc.lazyLoad"])"

Comment: always included ozlazyload.js and angular-material.js

Comment: ok so are you getting any errors now? and I can't see the dependent js files being included codepen? I can't help u if u can't recreate the error

Comment: @CaoYongFeng Change the order of files  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRLrdz , move ocLazyLoad.core.js below angular material

Comment: i fixed it. thank you very muth. i created a service of register service.

Comment: Great. glad that I could be of help :)